# Java Web - Load data from database into a textbox on page load

Tags: database, jsp, servlets, web, textbox

Let us say that I have a jsp page called **ChangeEmail.jsp** and a servlet called **ChangeEmailServlet.java**.  In the jsp page, I have a textbox containing the user's current e-mail address.  This is fetched from the database.  I want to let the user change the value in the textbox.

How can I load the e-mail address from the database in the textbox on page load?  Preferrably, I want to do this in the servlet and not in the jsp page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am explaining basic flow How you should design Web Application Flow.

Do not access "ChangeEmail.jsp" directly. Create a Servlet which acts as `Controller` and based upon parameter e,g, "`pageName=ChangeEmail`".

Forward to JSP from Servlet and before you forward, perform business logic using `Model` and store values in `request` or `session` scope again as per your need. 
(Here is your case its fetching email address from database).

Access the attributes in JSP which is your `View`.

This completes your `MVC` architecture as well.